# How to combine multiple .txt files in Unix based on time it is created. (Starting with first created file and ending with last created file)

Tags: unix

I have below list of files in one folder with creation date and time.

```
1. A.txt - 23/Feb/2016 14:05:00
2. B.txt - 23/Feb/2016 13:05:00
3. C.txt - 22/Feb/2016 14:05:00
4. D.txt - 22/Feb/2016 13:05:00
```

I want to combine these files into one single text file in the sequence in which they are created. Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -t1| xargs cat > newfile.txt
```